# Create project using Fortify Software Security Center REST API

Tags: python, rest, fortify

Can I create projects using the HP Fortify SSC's REST API?  This works beautifully to grab a list of projects:

```
import requests
import getpass
import json

url = "https://www.example.com/ssc/api/v1/"
endpoint = "auth/obtain_token"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Accept": "application/json"}
username = getpass.getuser()
password = getpass.getpass()
auth = (username, password)

r = requests.post("{url}{endpoint}".format(url=url, endpoint=endpoint), headers=headers, auth=auth)

data = r.json().get("data")
token = data.get("token")
endpoint = "projects"
headers["Authentication"] = "FortifyToken {token}".format(token=token)

r = requests.get("{url}{endpoint}".format(url=url, endpoint=endpoint), headers=headers)

print json.dumps(r.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

... But I don't see any examples in the API documentation for actually *creating* a project.  I am specifically interested in doing so using the Python requests library.  I do **NOT** want to have to do anything in Java (which is what all of the samples that come with the Fortify SSC WAR package are).

If anyone has any experience with the SSC REST API (or can point me to some better documentation), I'd appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: just wanted to know whether you were able to make any progress or not? I am also trying to write python client. It would be really appreciate if you provide some input.

Comment: that is great. I am really looking forward your answer. Just ping me once you are done. Thanks.

Comment: I am also working on python client. It is still work in progress. here is the link: https://github.com/rakeshcusat/python-hpfortify

Comment: I see two solutions in Python, by ellerm in the HP (MicroFocus) forum, https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Fortify-Questions/How-to-create-application-in-SSC-with-REST-API/qaq-p/1553209 and by Target https://github.com/target/fortifyapi. Wow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got some good information out of HPE technical support, and was able to put together a script for creating projects using the SSC REST API in Python.  The newest version of the SSC (17.10) makes this much easier with the Swaggerized REST API.

Comment: did you also write api to upload the source code? if you did can you share it?

Comment: I feel like the swaggerized rest api has been around since 16.10.

Comment: @jt1981 can you please share your script

Answer (score 2):

I have written an open [source python library](https://github.com/locationlabs/python-hpfortify) which can be used by useful here.
This is easy to use and it also provide a command line tool to upload the source code for static code scan.

Comment: The file hpfortify/base.py has this line, BASE_URL_US = "https://api.hpfod.com" so I guess it will not connect to an on-premise SSC server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the authors of [SonarQube Fortify plugin](https://github.com/abnamrocoesd/sonarqube-fortify-plugin/blob/master/fortify-util/ssc-util/src/main/java/com/fortify/ssc/connection/SSCAuthenticatingRestConnection.java) (not Fortify SSC documentation and not its autogenerated ssc/html/docs/api-reference), I figured I needed to base64-encode the token.

```
if len(auth) == 1:
    headers.update((("Authorization", "FortifyToken " + base64.b64encode(auth[0])),))
elif len(auth) == 2:
    headers.update((("Authorization", "Basic " + base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(*auth))),))
```

The `auth/token` call helps avoid resending the user name/password pair. The fortifyclient script from Fortify SCA bin directory can execute the call beforehand.